# Where is this steeple, these palm trees, flats in Hong Kong?

Tags: identify-this, hong-kong

My brother's family lives Hong Kong, and  my niece is wearing graduation cap second from left. She graduated from Hong Kong University. Therefore I think this picture was taken in H.K.

But this doesn't look like H.K.U. and noone remembers where!

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is HKU, the two towers in the background are Kingfield Towers A & B. They're on Bonham Road.

https://www.google.com/maps/place/83-73+Bonham+Rd,+Hong+Kong/@22.2847758,114.1372795,501m/data=!3m2!1e3!4b1!4m12!1m6!3m5!1s0x0:0x2c48f5d3cd6fc8d8!2sThe+University+of+Hong+Kong!8m2!3d22.2829989!4d114.1370848!3m4!1s0x3403ff841fa882c5:0x8dd8992c811541c3!8m2!3d22.2847745!4d114.1378266

Answer (score 7):

This is actually right in HKU, the main building’s tower is easily recognisable.

This would be nearly exactly here: https://goo.gl/maps/4ibfStg4nfUu1TCfA